# How can I make these two circles the same size? please help me

Tags: circles

[image]

here's the code:
\node[circle, draw=black, solid] (Q9) at (10.5,-1.5){Q9};
\node[circle, draw=black, solid] (Q10) at (9.0, -1.5){Q10};

Comment: Look up the [minimum width] (p 230) and [text width] (p 235) options for nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you post a minimal working example (MWE) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Anyway, I came up with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw=black, solid] (Q9) at (10.5,-1.5){\phantom{Q10}};
\node at (Q9) {Q9};
\node[circle, draw=black, solid] (Q10) at (9.0, -1.5){Q10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the next output:

[image: output]

Notice how I put `{\phantom{Q10}}` in the first `\node` to get the spacing of Q10, and in the line below, I place the text Q9 at the coordinate (Q9).

Comment: thank you. I really appreciate it. but I still have a question. how can I add a subscript(number) in Q. just like Q_10 in latex. I tried. but it doesn't work and it will report an error.

Comment: The error is beacause the subscript written that way must be inside math mode.
If you only need numbers, you could do ```Q$_{10}$``` if you want an upright Q, or ```$Q_{10}$``` for an italic Q.
If you plan to have text in the subscript, another option would be ```Q\textsubscript{10}```.
And well, to have the correct spacing, you should change that as well inside the ```\phantom``` command

Comment: thank you. have a good day